# Border of td is not showing on word-wrap break-word

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with proper structure. I have added style table layout fixed and td with word-wrap break word. The issue is that border is not coming properly. Please check out pic

[image]

the table style is

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  white-space: normal;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

the complete html 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide full example in snipped too? Have you checked other browsers?

Comment: float on td... why are using float on td?

Comment: can you provide html of this table?

Comment: @ChandaniPatel Please check the html.

Answer (score 1):

The following Solution will help you

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  white-space: normal;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
th{
  border: 1px solid black;

}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders Maria Anders Maria Anders Maria Anders Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```